# redis send_command error not found

Tags: python, redis

Using redis and following the tutorials from http://nullege.com/codes/search/redis.Redis.send_command

When trying this example:

```
results = r.send_command(
        'ZRANGEBYSCORE %s 0 %s LIMIT 0 %s\r\n' % (
            qk,
            ts,
            limit
```

In my case i am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Redis' object has no attribute 'send_command'
```

Comment: What is your `r`? Where is it coming from?

Answer (score 0):

And redis.Redis hasnt method send_command(). This is a method of the Connection class.
https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/redis/connection.py